# load function js

Tags: javascript

Имеется такой HTML:

```
<div class="asd">
    <div class="das selected"></div>
    <div class="das"></div>
    <div class="das"></div>
    <div class="das"></div>
    <div class="das"></div>
</div>
```

Через каждые 5 секунд `selected` меняется у блоков, и имеется такой код:

```
$(function() {
    $(".asd").html('<span class="disb"></span>');
    $(".asd.selected").html('<span class="act"></span>');
});
```

Как сделать так, чтобы скрипт отрабатывал всегда, а не только когда документ загрузился?

Comment: Не понятно, как сейчас «через каждые 5 сек» меняется что-то? В приведённом коде после выполнения все внутренние `div`'ы пропадут и вместо них будет только `<span class="disb"/>`

Answer (score 1):

```
window.setInterval(
    function(){
      $(".asd").html('<span class="disb"></span>');
      $(".asd.selected").html('<span class="act"></span>');
    }
    , 5000
)
```

Через каждые 5 секунд выполнится функция.